# Преобразовать строку в число типа хэша

Tags: php

Подскажите, как можно текстовую строку преобразовать в число, скажем, от 50 до 100? Что-то типа хэша, чтобы из одной и той же строки всегда получалось одно и то же число.

Comment: проссумировать odr($ch), взять по модулю 50, прибавить 50

Comment: `crc32(str) % 50 + 50`

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо, этот вариант работает.